# Actions on Google Request Sync returns http error 500

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

When I make the request sync of one agentUserId, it returns me the http error 500, but I don't know why.

I have also figured out that I can't execute any request from the Google Home app, but if I change email connected with that agentUserId the request synch works fine and I can command my devices without any problem.

I have also figured out that if I change agentUserId associated with my domotic both the accounts works and can command the devices. It seems that the couple email and agentUserId is banned or some kind of.

I had already written to Google support but they told me to write here. If anyone can help it will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is difficult to understand exactly what the problem you're encountering is, or what you are doing that causes the error. Updating your question with the source you're using, the Intents that you think should be triggered, the exact conversation that is causing the problem, and the exact error messages you're getting, we may be better able to help you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about writing questions that help us to help you.

Comment: Is one of your accounts a GSuite account?

Comment: no it isn't a GSuite account, but the strange things is that the Google Home app says that there was a problem with my application, but if i watch my logger on the endpoit that handle the request from google i don't see any request from google. I log all the request before making any parsing that could cause maybe some exception to be clear.

Comment: New [error logging features](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/monitoring-logging) have been enabled for Smart Home Actions - these may be helpful for you to more clearly identify the issue if you are still having issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the HTTP 500 error code is being returned means that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to respond and something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is. So it is difficult to pinpoint exact the reason without further debugging.
And as mentioned in the comments that you don't see any request from Google in the logger indicates that the "agentUserdId" associated with the user (& sent in the original SYNC request) might not exist. But further debugging is required to find out the root cause of this issue and do the following,

- Make sure the agenUserId is valid, previously reported in a sync response and doesn't include any special/invalid characters.
- You have enabled HomeGraphAPI, and signing the requests properly as stated in https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/request-sync
- Make sure the agentUserId you interact with does exist, and have devices in HomeGraph. You can use devices.sync (https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rest/v1/devices/sync) Rest API to verify this